# After HDMI disconnected, no image on built in monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

When I unplug HDMI cable, no image goes to built-in monitor. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug [link](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11627&fbclid=IwAR1YfRHuneAIYmSsJVxG661sPau6HmXhGqrXMu3PKNQERz-8XVCNMXkK86Q), but it has an work around.

It is solved with:

```
xrandr --auto
```

So, you can assign a shortcut to it or type on the console oppened with Ctrl+Alt+F4.

You will have to do it everytime you lose image by unplugging HDMI.

Comment: This does make an image appear on the built-in screen again.  However, if the external monitor was set to a higher resolution than the built-in screen, the built-in screen seems to keep that, so that most of the desktop area is off-screen.  Which then makes it difficult (impossible?) to reset this e.g. by pressing Win and trying to open the Displays settings...